# How to get access token from SAML response in browser?

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, rest, saml-2.0, onelogin

I have one application with onelogin SAML 2.0 configured using **Spring boot Java and REST web services (microservice architecture) and angularjs** in front end. I am getting SAML response in java code. From there how to redirect to UI and pass the token in the browser.

Comment: You need to read the SAML response and parse it... Does the SAML response contain token?

Comment: @Chetan I have already parsed the SAML response. But I can't see the token field there. Please find the below Response.
OnceSAML login is successful, we wants one login to redirect the response to Angular but it was not possible so we gave Rest api URL . We are receiving the saml response to that api but we r not getting the control on the front end

Comment: Hmm... I think once you receive the SAML from the Identity provider that means the user login is successfully.. Now your service should create a new token using the information about the user you received in the SAML and pass that token to the angular...

Comment: @Chetan We are processing the SAML response in Rest api and according to response status , We are sending back the token. But since front end is not having control over that rest api (Since one login is calling that api), I am unable to process the response.

Comment: Generally, you don't trust a front-end like Angular to make a security decision. Can you be sure that front-end hasn't been modified? Anyway, I would suggest (if you need to do SAML with an external IdP) that you convert the SAML assertion to OIDC on the server-side, and retrieve the data in the assertion via a userinfo endpoint call.